# AS3 AIR Mobile (iOS and Android) UI options

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I am developing an AIR app for mobile and been searching around for UI components/extensions but have only come across Feathers which is still a little buggy. I was wondering if anyone had any good resources to achieve:

- Dropdown/selectable list
- Data/item list
- Input fields

I would love if I could use the native options but understand if it's not possible.

Comment: Have you looked at Flextras? https://www.flextras.com/

Comment: I've had luck with MADComponents (Mobile Application Development Components): [link](http://code.google.com/p/mad-components/)

Comment: Thanks to both for the options.